# jQuery remove selected element, dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I have a form and I can dynamically add more lines but if I try to remove a specific line it does not work, however the first line gets removed with no problem.

Here is the html:

```
<form class="order-form">
  <div class="product-lines">
<!-- Product Line Section -->
  <div class="product-line">                
<a href="#" alt="close" class="btn-close" title="Remove"><img alt="remove" src="img/close.png"  /></a>
<input class="input-text" name="product-code" type="text" placeholder="Product Code" ></input>
<input class="input-text" name="product-quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity"></input>
<input class="input-text" name="product-discript" type="text" placeholder="Discription of Product"></input>
<label class="label-sign">&pound;</label>
<input class="input-text" name="product-price" type="text" placeholder="RRP Price"></input>
<br>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="product-btn">                  
<input name="btn-add-line" type="button" value="Add new line"></input>
<input name="btn-update" type="button" value="Update"></input>
<input name="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit Order"></input>
<label class="label-sign">&pound;</label>
<input class="input-text" name="order-info" type="text" placeholder="Order total" ></input>
</div>                  
</form>
```

The jQuery code I have tried:

```
$(".btn-close").on("click", function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().remove();   
});
```

I've also Tried

```
$(e.currentTarget).parents("div.product-lines).next("div.product-line).remove();
```

Any help would be most appreciated, also a explanation would be very helpful for me to learn.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ - so `$(document).on('click', '.btn-close', function(){...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try something like**

```
$(".product-lines").on("click", ".btn-close", function(e){

    $(e.currentTarget).parent().remove();   

});
```

You cannot attach events to objects that are not currently on page (lines).
You have to attach click event on **product-lines** object and when it is clicked you **delegate** event to "closest" **product-line** object!

Comment: @Arun P Johny Reading event degradation now, Thanks!

Comment: @Zinox funny, but delegation non degradation

Comment: @elrado how do I keep the the first line from now being deleted (basically leaving 1 line still on the page)

Comment: hmm don't add btn-close to it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to changed the jQuery slightly to allow for [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This means all elements added in future will get the event attached to them too.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-close", function(e){

   $(e.currentTarget).parent().remove();   

});
```

Comment: Thank you for that works! I was just reading up on event degradation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click','button id/class',function(){

$(e.currentTarget).parent().remove(); 
});
```

but if u use this code it will remove `<div class="product-line">...</div>`

why you want to remove this div.

i dont get your question very well. Explain in details and step by step .

Comment: Thank You! I was just reading event degradation, You are right I just realized I do not want the main line to be deleted. Any thought on how to not delete the main one. I hope this question makes sense.